# Windows Server 2012 R2, DHCP from Hyper-V VM don't work

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, ip, dhcp-server, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have an `AD DC` with `DHCP` with leases, reservations and so on. I created a VM with `WS2012r2`, and promoted it to a `DC`.

After that I added the `DHCP` role to the new server. On the original server I backed up the existing `DCHP` configuration, restored it on the new `DHCP` server and unathorized the old `DHCP` server. All of the configurations were loaded correctly but the new `VM` does not lease IPs.

When I enable `DHCP` in VM in the same `Hyper-V` host, then the VM DHCP work fine.

I had searched on [Google](https://google.com) but I was unable to find a solution.

What is the cause?

Comment: I have the same problem...Can you tell me if you had solved the problem

Comment: Did you authorize the new DHCP server? Anything in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if DHCP ports are not being blocked also provide logs related to DHCP that are being generated in systems of eventvwr.

Please explain "When I enable DHCP in VM in the same Hyper-V host, then the VM DHCP work fine."

from above what i understand is you kept the servers IP dynamic and found the server is able to receive an IP, If so did you check after reassigning static IP to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I mean, when I start another ie Win7 VM in the same Hyper-V host that run the WS2012 R2, then the Win7 VM get the DHCP IP without problem, nevertheless, when I try to obtain the same result from another workstation in the lan, not discovery the server. I have ping response of the WS2012 VM from any workstation in the lan, and the ports are open. I don't know what is happening yet.

Comment: Can you please check below 3 links, if it can help you with your issue.

http://www.virtualizationteam.com/server-virtualization/dhcp-is-not-working-on-ms-windows-2008-hyper-v.html

https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1154966-hyper-v-dhcp-issues-fixed/

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/251317-hyper-v-vm-not-leasing-ip-s-dhcp.

Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I was checked these links and all comment, but no one had solved my problem, still with the same. Thanks a lot anyway!